# Strange GetWindowText(); error

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to get the text of a `textedit` control in a `dialog` in my Win32 C++ Application.
I am using the following block of code to get that, and also to test it.

```
HWND hCarRegNo = GetDlgItem( hDlg, IDC_REGNUMBER );

if( hCarRegNo )
{
    LPWSTR carRegNo = NULL;
    GetWindowText(hCarRegNo, carRegNo, 20);
    MessageBox(hDlg, carRegNo, _T("Test"), MB_OK);
}
```

The `MessageBox` output is an empty string.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: *Always* assert the return value of a winapi function.  You'd have easily seen GetWindowText fail on the null pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not allocating any memory for carRegNo. Try this

```
WCHAR carRegNo[20];
GetWindowText(hCarRegNo, carRegNo, 20);
```

Comment: which is the best? `THCAR` or `WCHAR` what is the difference between these two?

Comment: WCHAR is a wide char, 16 bits, and it's used for Unicode support. TCHAR can be either wide (16 bits) or narrow (8 bits) depending on your compiler settings. Since all modern Windows computers use 16 bit characters (you have to go back to Windows ME for a version of Windows that uses narrow chars) WCHAR is better.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, I have solved the problem: instead of `LPWSTR`, I had to use `TCHAR carRegNo[256]` to make this work.

```
HWND hCarRegNo = GetDlgItem( hDlg, IDC_REGNUMBER );

if( hCarRegNo )
{
    TCHAR carRegNo[256] = L"";
    GetWindowText(hCarRegNo, carRegNo, 256);
    MessageBox(hDlg, carRegNo, _T("Test"), MB_OK);
}
```

Comment: That's better, but your array is size 256 but you tell GetWindowText it's only size 20. You should be consistent.

Comment: You should dynamically allocate the buffer based on `GetWindowTextLength()`, that way you can handle more than 256 character without wasting memory unnecessarily.